# Differences between "a X of a Y" and "the X of a Y"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

A car usually is equipped with four wheels.
And below "wheel" doesn't mean a steering wheel.

> (1) a wheel of a car

Does (1) implies there is more than one wheel?

> (2) the wheel of a car

Does (2) implies there is only one wheel?

---

> (3) a backseat of a car.

Does (3) implies there is more than one backseat?

> (4) the backseat of a car.

Does (4) implies there is only one backseat?

---

Interestingly, I found stock photos often uses "a X of a Y" like the case below

> Businessman sitting on a backseat of the car using smart phone.

Source:
https://www.westend61.de/en/imageView/CJMF00085/businessman-sitting-on-a-backseat-of-the-car-using-smartphone?window=1

> Businessman sitting on a backseat of a car using smartphone and looking around.

Source:
https://www.westend61.de/en/imageView/CJMF00083/businessman-sitting-on-a-backseat-of-a-car-using-smartphone-and-looking-around?window=1

Comment: a means generally, the means specific. That is all you need.

Comment: [please correct: Does X imply etc.]

Comment: "backseat of a car" can either refer to the entire bench seat from door to door, or each part of that seat that is big enough for someone's bum (and probably has its own seatbelt). So it's inherently ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Your “an x of a y” example does indeed imply that there is more than one “x”, but not necessarily only one “y”, for that we’d say, for example:

> A wheel of **the** car.

“The x of a y” does indeed imply that a y only has one x.

The last example you mentioned is not good English, and is actually from a German website (“.de”).

Comment: So, can I say "the X of a Y" implies there is only one "X"? Do the same rules of  "the X of a Y" and "an X of a Y" apply to both animate and inanimate objects?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I’ve added that to my answer. Yes, I believe this would apply to both animate and inanimate objects, but if you have a particular example that is concerning you I’d be happy to consider it.

Answer (score -1):

Businessman sitting on a backseat of a car using smartphone and looking around.

The above sentence is not correct.

Correct one :-
A businessman is sitting in the backseat of a car using a smartphone and looking around.

You can check on any online free grammar checker

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135455)